# Clear filters on multiple protected sheet in Excel using a single button in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying create a button that would remove filters applied to one or more columns in a single click.
But as I have a protected sheets I need to unprotect and protect sheets in the code for this work
This method worked but it took about 2 sec as I have 4 protected sheets.
Then I got the idea to use an If condition.

```
Sub Resetauto()
On Error GoTo Handler

 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 If ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet3" Then
 Sheets("Sheet3").Unprotect Password:="pass"
 ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Sort.SortFields _
    .Clear
 ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
 Sheets("Sheet3").Protect _
 Password:="pass", _
 UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
 AllowFiltering:=True, _
 AllowSorting:=True, _
 AllowUsingPivotTables:=True

 ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1" Then
 Sheets("Sheet1").Unprotect Password:="pass"
 ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Sort.SortFields _
    .Clear
 ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
Sheets("Sheet1").Protect _
Password:="pass", _
UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
AllowFiltering:=True, _
AllowSorting:=True, _
AllowUsingPivotTables:=True

ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet4" Then
Sheets("Sheet4").Unprotect Password:="pass"
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Sort.SortFields _
    .Clear
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
Sheets("Sheet4").Protect _
Password:="Pass", _
UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
AllowFiltering:=True, _
AllowSorting:=True, _
AllowUsingPivotTables:=True

Else
Sheets("Sheet5").Unprotect Password:="pass"
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Sort.SortFields _
    .Clear
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
Sheets("Sheet5").Protect _
Password:="pass", _
UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
AllowFiltering:=True, _
AllowSorting:=True, _
AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub

Handler:
Sheets("Sheet1").Protect _
Password:="pass", _
UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
AllowFiltering:=True, _
AllowSorting:=True, _
AllowUsingPivotTables:=True

Sheets("Sheet2").Protect _
Password:="pass", _
UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
AllowFiltering:=True, _
AllowSorting:=True, _
AllowUsingPivotTables:=True

Sheets("Sheet3").Protect _
Password:="pass", _
UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
AllowFiltering:=True, _
AllowSorting:=True, _
AllowUsingPivotTables:=True

Sheets("Sheet5").Protect _
Password:="pass", _
UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
AllowFiltering:=True, _
AllowSorting:=True, _
AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

This code doesn't do anything, My cursor rotates for 2 sec..It doesn't remove the filter

Is there something wrong in my code??

Comment: if you remove error handler, will VBA give you a debug? [Code Review](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-review) folks could also help with some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no errors being ignored by the OnError handler, my suggestion would be to replace ElseIf with separate If statements. I find those to be a trap.